# Change language setting For MS Excel

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, language, format

I've installed an Excel 2013 (English) on a Server 2012 R2 (English) and all but one part of Excel is in english.

When formatting cells and choosing Custom Number the formats referring to dates is displayed as "dd/mm/åååå" (Danish language reference), instead of "dd/mm/yyyy".
Does any one know how I can change this as it's bothering some of our english users.
The language and regional settings in Windows is set to english (UK) standards.

Answer (score 0):

Shortly after posting this I found the answer to my own question:
The display is tied into the language settings in use in the current session.
Changing the preffered language in the language settings in control panel to english/united kingdom also changed the display to be dd/mm/yyyy instead of dd/mm/åååå in excel.